# A rarely mentioned Vulkan function "vkCmdUpdateBuffer()", what is it used for?

Tags: vulkan

This seems to be a simple Vulkan API question but I really can not find answer after search Internet.
I noticed there is a Vulkan function:

```
void vkCmdUpdateBuffer(
    VkCommandBuffer                             commandBuffer,
    VkBuffer                                    dstBuffer,
    VkDeviceSize                                dstOffset,
    VkDeviceSize                                dataSize,
    const void*                                 pData);
```

At first glance, I thoughts it can be used to record the command buffer since it has prefix `vkCmd` in its name, but the document says that

> vkCmdUpdateBuffer is only allowed outside of a render pass. This command is treated as “transfer” operation, for the purposes of synchronization barriers.

So I start thinking that it is a convenience function that wraps the buffer data transferring operation like using `memcpy()` to copy the data from host to the device.

Then my question is: Why there is NOT a single Vulkan sample / tutorial (I have searched all of them) using `vkCmdUpdateBuffer()` instead of manually coping data by `memcpy()`. Did I understand it wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What does it matter that tutorials don't talk about it?

Comment: @NicolBolas  The lack of a function in multiple tutorials may hint at a the new-ness of said function, issues with the function on a technical level (bugs or useless-ness), or, as this case is here, the desire for such a function to be used in select circumstances.  It is important to distinguish between these situations in order to avoid misinformation about an API to be spread, or misuse of certain utilities.  It *does* matter on some level when you don't see part of an API used or mentioned.

Comment: @opa: My issue is that what you've said rests on the assumption that tutorial usage in any way represents *real world usage*. Given the general quality of tutorials on the Internet, I don't think this is a reasonable way to look at things.

Comment: @NicolBolas Sure, it is true that tutorials don't represent real world usage in general, but, especially to people new to an API, such tutorials are the *only* authority on how real wold usage looks like when no other easily accessible source of information can be uncovered. It looks suspicious when none of the learning material mentions a function of an API no matter how advanced, esp when it presents an alternative method to doing something.  It doesn't matter that objectively tutorials don't reflect real world usage when they are practically the only searchable source for standard practice.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. Without seeing any sample code of using it, I can not imagine a good case to use it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All `vkCmd*` functions generate commands into a command buffer. This one is no exception. It is a transfer command, and like most transfer commands, you don't get to do them within a render pass. But there are plenty of command buffer generating commands that don't work in render passes.

Normally Vulkan memory transfer operations only happen between device memory. The typical mechanism for the host to put something in device memory is to write to a mapped pointer. But by definition, that requires that the destination memory be mappable. So if you want to write something to non-mappable memory, you have to copy it to mappable memory, then do a transfer operation between the mappable memory to the non-mappable memory via `vkCmdCopy*` functions.

And that's fine if you're doing a bunch of transfers all at once. You can copy a bunch of stuff into mapped memory, then submit a batch containing all of the copy operations to copy the data into the appropriate locations.

But sometimes, you're just updating a small piece of device memory. If it's not mappable, then that's a lot of work to do just to get a few kilobytes of data to the GPU. In that case, `vkCmdUpdateBuffer` may be the better choice, since it can "directly" copy from CPU memory to any device memory.

I say "directly" because that's obviously not what it's doing. It's really doing the same thing you would have done, except it's doing it within the command buffer. You would have copied your CPU data into GPU mappable memory, then created a command that copies from that mappable memory into non-mappable memory.

`vkCmdUpdateBuffer` does the exact same thing. It copies the data from the pointer/size you give it into mappable memory (which is provided by the *command buffer itself*. This is why it has an upper limit of 64KB). This copy happens *immediately*, just as it would have if you did a `memcpy`, so when this function returns, you can do whatever you want with the pointer you gave it. Then it creates a command in the command buffer that copies from the mappable memory in the command buffer to the destination memory location.

[The documentation for this function](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/chap18.html#clears-updating-buffers) explicitly gives warnings about using it for larger transfers. That is, it tells you *not to do that*. This is for quick, *small*, one-shot updates of unmappable memory. Nothing more.

That's one reason why tutorials don't talk about it: it's a highly special-case function that many novice users will try to use because it's easier than the explicit code. But in most cases, they should not be using it.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, I'll need a bit more time to make sure I completely understand it.

Comment: In most of samples I have studied, people would like to create a device vkBuffer and keep it mapped, so that it is handy (and with better performance) to use memcopy() to copy the data to the buffer. So the biggest question for me is: what is really user case for vkCmdUpdateBuffer()? Under what circumstance we need to bother use it instead of memcpy()?

Comment: @HongkunWang: As I said: "This is for quick, small, one-shot updates of unmappable memory. Nothing more."

Comment: Got it. That's why there is no good chance to demonstrate it in samples / tutorials.

Comment: What about uniforms in device-local (non-host-visible) memory?

Comment: @RnMss: Um... what about them? That's something you could use this function for, but you could also just not have frequently updated uniforms live in device-local memory.